# MySQL Cluster + Manager and NDB/J

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cluster-computing

I've been trying to setup a MySQL Cluster for a few days using the MySQL Cluster Manager on 3 Ubuntu nodes (3 identical VM instances with 1GB RAM each).

I've followed the video on MySQL Cluster Manager on the MySQL site. There's not much other documentation/tutorials on it (probably because it's a commercial product).

I start the cluster and show the status, but the mysqld nodes never start, they just remain as "added". If I install mysql-server using "sudo apt-get install mysql-server" then I get the normal local server running and the nodes register as "started", but I can't see how to connect to the cluster rather than the individual MySQL servers running on the mysqld nodes.

I'm also at a loss as to how the Java connector for MySQL Cluster is organised, it appears that there are multiple libraries so I don't even know which library I need or how to get them (some are created when compiling MySQL Cluster???). Could someone please explain how the connectors work to interact with NDB from Java and how to get them?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the official documentation for MySQL Cluster Manager can be found by navigating to the Cluster documentation on dev.mysql.com (called "MySQL Cluster Manager"). You are correct that MySQL Cluster Manager is commercial software although MySQL Cluster itself is available under a commercial or GPL license.

It sounds as though you've already configured the agents and have them running and so if you want to get a Cluster up and running quickly then refer to this [simple worked example of using MySQL Cluster Manager](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/mysql-cluster-manager-1-1-available/)

In terms of understanding why the MySQL Servers (mysqlds) are not starting up, there aren't many clues in your question and so we need to narrow it down (one reason could be if you had multiple mysqlds defined on the same host that are trying to use the default port (3306)).

To check what the manager has been doing, take a look in the file called mysql-cluster-manager.log. You can adjust the level of logging using the cluster manager configuration file.

To see what MySQL Cluster itself thinks has happened, check the directories storing the cluster data files (if you haven't over-written the defaults then this would be under /clusters/ and then you'll see a directory for each node in the cluster). The first one to check is ndb__cluster.log and other logs that you'll find in the "data" sub-directory of the id associated with the ndb_mgmd node. There will also be per-node log files so also check the mysqld_*out.err and mysqld*_out.log files stored in the data directory associated with mysqld node-ids.

Most important point is do **not** use the mysqld that gets installed with "sudo apt-get install mysql-server" as this version will not be compatible with MySQL Cluster - always use the binaries that come with the MySQL Cluster tar ball (or if using Cluster Manager that should be transparent to you anyway.

Note that if you want to get MySQL Cluster up and running on a single host without MySQL Cluster Manager then refer to the quick-start guide located on the MySQL Cluster download site (on mysql.com rather than e-Delivery).

For the java access, try out this [MySQL Cluster ClusterJ tutorial](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/using-clusterj-part-of-mysql-cluster-connector-for-java-a-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I started afresh and restarted the cluster when the mysqld nodes didn't change to started. The cluster is up and working now.

I see that ClusterJ requires you create a class for each table you want to interact with in order to use it. Unfortunately I can't do this because I need to be able to interact with tables that will be created during operation and therefore I cannot predict the structure of. Are there any Java libraries for NDB that have a Map interface or something of that nature? Thanks for the help so far.